# Problems with postgres database / syncdb after Heroku Django setup

Tags: database, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm new to the Heroku / Django / Postgres game, and running into trouble after following the instructions in their [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django). Here's my setup:

Installed:
Django 1.4.5
dj_database_url
Postgress.app 9.2.2.0

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'db_name',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
 }
}
```

and later on in settings.py:

```
import dj_database_url
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

When I run python manage.py syncdb:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/joerobinson/.virtualenvs/dg/lib/python2.7/site-         packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Users/joerobinson/.virtualenvs/dg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/joerobinson/.virtualenvs/dg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/joerobinson/.virtualenvs/dg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/joerobinson/.virtualenvs/dg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/joerobinson/.virtualenvs/dg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/Users/joerobinson/.virtualenvs/dg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

When I run python manage.py shell, import settings, and look at DATABASES, I get:

```
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'NAME': '', 'TEST_CHARSET': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'PORT': '', 'HOST': '', 'USER': '', 'TEST_NAME': None, 'PASSWORD':
```

So I know I must be configuring something improperly, but I haven't found the right settings in a night of searching. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to point configure the database URL as follows:

```
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost/db_name')
```

I had other issues relating to the psycopg2 package and gcc-4.2, but those aren't covered by my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a real Django database backend, not `django.db.backends.dummy`. For example:

```
{'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', ... }
```

Comment: Yes, I definitely want that. Problem is that I'm not sure where django.db.backends.dummy is getting inserted. Must be this line: DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(). How do I give dj_database_url.config() the database default I set up above?

Comment: @Joe Ah, ok. Sorry. Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/a/3249215/398670 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947618/django-tutorial-says-i-havent-set-database-engine-setting-yet-but-i-have ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved same issue by deleting dummy/base.py and creating symlink to it:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py
```